# How do I Gradual Zoom In while changing color on Mouse Hover and Gradual Zoom Out and fading color on mouse house

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i am trying to achieve is gradually zoom the image while having it color change with the new image. For example the image apple with black color and i have another image apple with red color. When you mouse hover on the black apple, it will gradually change it color turning to red. The problem is when I hover the mouse, it changes to the other image instantly and then zoom out. Any ideas? or is it possible in jquery?

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

```
    // Start Documentation
    $(document).ready(function () {


        //  About Us Title Text

        $('.about_us_img,.about_us_txt').mouseover(function () {
            {

                $('.about_us_img').animate({
                    width: "216px"
                }, 400);
                $('.about_us_txt').css({
                    color: '#49968b'
                });

                $('.about_us_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: newSizeAU
                }, 300);

                $('.about_us_img').attr("src", AboutHut);
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 0.9);

            }
        });

        $('.about_us_img,.about_us_txt').mouseout(function () {
            {

                $('.about_us_img').animate({
                    width: "196px"
                }, 400);
                $('.about_us_txt').css({
                    color: '#000'
                });

                $('.about_us_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: oldSizeAU
                }, 300);
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 1);
                $('.about_us_img ').attr("src", OrigHut);

            }
        });
        var oldSizeAU = parseFloat($('.about_us_txt').css('font-size'));
        var newSizeAU = oldSizeAU * 1.1;


        //Our Project



        $('.our_project_img,.our_project_txt').mouseover(function () {
            {

                $('.our_project_img').animate({
                    width: "216px"
                }, 400);
                $('.our_project_txt').css({
                    color: '#b26c64'
                });

                $('.our_project_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: newSizePR
                }, 300);
                $('.our_project_img').attr("src", ProjectHut);
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 0.9);
            }
        });

        $('.our_project_img,.our_project_txt').mouseout(function () {
            {

                $('.our_project_img').animate({
                    width: "196px"
                }, 400);
                $('.our_project_txt').css({
                    color: '#000'
                });

                $('.our_project_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: oldSizePR
                }, 300);
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 1);
                $('.our_project_img').attr("src", OrigHut);

            }
        });
        var oldSizePR = parseFloat($('.our_project_txt').css('font-size'));
        var newSizePR = oldSizePR * 1.1;


        //My Profile



        $('.my_profile_img,.my_profile_txt').mouseover(function () {
            {
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 0.9);
                $('.my_profile_img').animate({
                    width: "216px"
                }, 400);
                $('.my_profile_txt').css({
                    color: '#8db262'
                });

                $('.my_profile_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: newSize
                }, 300);
                $('.my_profile_img').attr("src", ProfileHut);

            }
        });

        $('.my_profile_img,.my_profile_txt').mouseout(function () {
            {

                $('.my_profile_img').animate({
                    width: "196px"
                }, 400);
                $('.my_profile_txt').css({
                    color: '#000'
                });

                $('.my_profile_txt').animate({
                    fontSize: oldSize
                }, 300);
                $(this).fadeTo('300', 1);
                $('.my_profile_img').attr("src", OrigHut);

            }
        });






        var oldSize = parseFloat($('.my_profile_txt').css('font-size'));
        var newSize = oldSize * 1.1;
        /****

$('.my_profile_img,.my_profile_txt').mouseover(function () {


    $('.my_profile_img,.my_profile_txt').fadeTo('slow', 0.8, function () {
        $('.my_profile_img').animate({
            width: newWidthSize
        }, 500);
        $('.my_profile_txt').animate({
            fontSize: NewSize
        }, 300);


        $(this).fadeTo('200', 1);
        $('.my_profile_img').attr('src', ProfileHut);


    });
});

$('.my_profile_img,.my_profile_txt').mouseout(function () {
    $('.my_profile_img').animate({
        width: oldWidthSize
    }, 500);
    $('.my_profile_txt').animate({
        fontSize: oldSize
    }, 300);

    $(this).fadeTo('300', 0.9, function () {

        $('.my_profile_img').attr('src', OrigHut);
        $(this).fadeTo('300', 1);
    });

});

var oldWidthSize = parseFloat($('.my_profile_img').css('width'));
var newWidthSize = oldWidthSize * 1.1;

**/


        // End Ready Documentation
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not support color animation. However, jQuery UI has a plugin that handles color animations (see the UI page for color animation here: http://jqueryui.com/animate/). You need to install jQuery UI first and use the plugin, which you find here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

There is also a great example on the plugin page.

Once you have the plugin installed, it should be easy to animate colors. The snippet below, taken from the plugin documentation, should give you an idea of how it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  background-color: #bada55;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> //jQuery UI
<script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script> //plugin
</head>
<body>
<button id="go">Simple</button>
<button id="sat">Desaturate</button>
<div id="block">Hello!</div>
<script>
jQuery("#go").click(function(){
  jQuery("#block").animate({
      backgroundColor: "#abcdef"
  }, 1500 );
});
jQuery("#sat").click(function(){
  jQuery("#block").animate({
      backgroundColor: jQuery.Color({ saturation: 0 })
  }, 1500 );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to transition between two images, and not change the color of a single image, is that right?

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L7Lvz/1/) (click on the minion) makes the minion enlarge, then fade away, then is replaced by Mickey Mouse. If this is the general thing you're looking for you could have two images, exactly the same size but different colors, and play with the sizes in the fiddle.

JS

```
$( ".imagediv" ).click(function(){

  $( "#minion" ).animate({
                          height: 400,
                          width: 300
                          }, 3000,
                         function() {
                                 $( "#minion" ).animate({
                                                opacity: 0
                                                         }, 1000,
                          function() {
                                      $('.imagediv').html( $('.hiddendiv img').clone() );
                                      });
                                     });

});//end click
```

Comment: thanks i manage to put an idea to your answer,is it possible to animate like 20 images on mouse hover  so the image color gradually change will happen

Comment: You can just change the click to a hover, and hover over 100 images. But the change in color, as mentioned by Gabriel Ferraz, is problematic. If you could provide more details, we might be able to help you better. Do you have one image, and one to change the color of that image? Or do you have two images, same general form, but two different colors - that you want to transition between?

Comment: ...do you have one image, and want to change the color... (responding to my spelling mistake above)